# Issue with defining the path of upload in php

Tags: php, directory, path

I am facing an issue with defining the path where my new uploaded image is to be saved, i gave various tries at it and did some google search too but it was of no good :(

This is how i have my current codes written :

```
<?php
//Checking if all values are passed or not, new image is optional

if(isset($_POST["pname"]) && isset($_POST["price"]) && isset($_POST["listed"]) && isset($_POST["link"])){

    $file = $_FILES['validatedCustomFile'];
    extract($file);
    //Formatting and Processing the image
    $name = $name;
    $nameTemp = $tmp_name;
    $size = $size;

    if($size !== 0){
        $error = $error;
            if($error === 0){
                $fileType = $type;
                $fileExt = explode('.', $name);
                $fileExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
                
                $allow = array('jpg','jpeg','png');
                
                if(in_array($fileExt, $allow)){
                    $new = "MeTesting.$fileExt";
                    $destination = "..../$new";
                 
                    
                    //Moving the file Now
                    
                   if( move_uploaded_file($nameTemp, $destination)){
                    
                   header("location:../mover.php");
                   exit();
                   }
                   else{
                       echo "Destination error";
                   }
                }
                else{
                    //Format is not supported
                    echo "Invalid Format";
                }
            }
            else{
                //Error in uploading
                echo "Error in upload";
            }
    }
    else{
        //New image is not uploaded, just process with data update
        echo "Image is not submitted.";
    }
}

?>
```

To define the destination, i have tried multiple ways like using ../../ and everything i could get on the net.

The issue is till the time i set it to ../(productUpdate folder) it works fine, then it stops working !

This is the structure of my file manager

Location of this file : public_html/admin/dashboard/productUpdate/upload.php

I wish to upload it to : public_html/productAssets

Thanks in advance for your help and for your time !

Regards

Comment: Likely not your direct issue, but this can easily bite you: `extract($file);` - better work with the `$file` array directly. e.g. `move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destination)` . Do you get the _"Destination error"_ ?

Comment: Yes, i am getting destination error. Its related to directory only, i have tried printing things and they are ok, as i said, its working if i take it just 1 directory back, after that, it causes issues

Comment: are you running this locally on your development machine? if so check you display all errors and warnings. if on a remote server, check you have error logging enabled and you log all errors and warnings. then check the error output for warnings. functions like `move_uploaded_file` often tell the reason as a warning why they return `false`. you need to check that warning to find out what is going on.

Comment: This is hosted live on my hosting. Even am confused on why the error_log file is not being created

Comment: Yes, that can happen. Let's check some details: if you have configured PHP to do error logging, the PHP error log is normally created _unless_ `log_errors` (ini setting) is not activated. however in a webserver environment (so called PHP server API (PHP SAPI)) there by default is the standard error channel. You then simply find the PHP errors in the webserver error log. check that one first for PHP errors and warnings. It is most often more straight forward then taking care to configure a dedicated PHP error logging. So before changing PHP configuration, go with the default config on server.

Comment: Hi, i am grateful for your time, i could find an alternative way to do it. What i did is i just uploaded the file to productDetails folder and over there, i used header to redirect to another php file that had rename command in it which moved it few directories back. Could solve my purpose though its not the exact solution. Am grateful to you for the efforts and time you spent, a big thanks again